# Google AdMob for PHP based Hybrid Mobile App

Tags: php, ios, admob, adsense, revenue

I have created a web app using PHP, Vanilla JS and Jquery that is 100% responsive and is created with the sole purpose of being used as a mobile application only. Once completed I will integrate it with Flutter WebView for generating an apk file. I will also later convert it to ios. This app is currently in development stage and I stand at a point where I need to integrate a revenue modal like Google Admob. However, I see that google only provides native android and ios sdks. Is there any way how I can integrate Admob with my PHP based mobile app? This can also be a Core PHP based library or plugin that is written to support Admob in a PHP based mobile responsive web app. Anything that can help.

Also, does Adsense and Admob provide same amount of revenue? Or, is there a difference between the earning potential of both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one Correct way to do this, all the other ways will get you a violation strike.

**You should use Admob in flutter** any other walkaround may get you blocked by Google FOREVER!

To answer your questions:

- There is no way to make Admob work on web
- Admob is better for mobile apps and Adsense is better for websites

Comment: I choose Adsense. On further research I found out Adsense is more profitable than Admob itself.